# Load STL from buffer (not path) in Three.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, three.js

I want to display a user-uploaded STL file using Three.js.

My file is sent to the front-end via a GET request: `res.sendFile(path)`. The problem is, I can't use that raw data to load a file without editing Three.js's loader!

Could someone help me edit the [STLLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js) to accept the result of `res.sendFile(path)` instead of a path (URL)?

After a week of head-scratching, I've had no luck!

Here's the code of STLLoader.js:

```
import {
  BufferAttribute,
  BufferGeometry,
  DefaultLoadingManager,
  FileLoader,
  Float32BufferAttribute,
  LoaderUtils,
  Vector3
} from "three/build/three.module.js";


var STLLoader = function ( manager ) {

    this.manager = ( manager !== undefined ) ? manager : DefaultLoadingManager;

};

STLLoader.prototype = {

    constructor: STLLoader,

    load: function ( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError ) {

        var scope = this;

        var loader = new FileLoader( scope.manager );
        loader.setPath( scope.path );
        loader.setResponseType( 'arraybuffer' );
        loader.load( url, function ( text ) {

            try {

                onLoad( scope.parse( text ) );

            } catch ( exception ) {

                if ( onError ) {

                    onError( exception );

                }

            }

        }, onProgress, onError );

    },

    setPath: function ( value ) {

        this.path = value;
        return this;

    },

    parse: function ( data ) {

        function isBinary( data ) {

            var expect, face_size, n_faces, reader;
            reader = new DataView( data );
            face_size = ( 32 / 8 * 3 ) + ( ( 32 / 8 * 3 ) * 3 ) + ( 16 / 8 );
            n_faces = reader.getUint32( 80, true );
            expect = 80 + ( 32 / 8 ) + ( n_faces * face_size );

            if ( expect === reader.byteLength ) {

                return true;

            }

            // An ASCII STL data must begin with 'solid ' as the first six bytes.
            // However, ASCII STLs lacking the SPACE after the 'd' are known to be
            // plentiful.  So, check the first 5 bytes for 'solid'.

            // Several encodings, such as UTF-8, precede the text with up to 5 bytes:
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding
            // Search for "solid" to start anywhere after those prefixes.

            // US-ASCII ordinal values for 's', 'o', 'l', 'i', 'd'

            var solid = [ 115, 111, 108, 105, 100 ];

            for ( var off = 0; off < 5; off ++ ) {

                // If "solid" text is matched to the current offset, declare it to be an ASCII STL.

                if ( matchDataViewAt( solid, reader, off ) ) return false;

            }

            // Couldn't find "solid" text at the beginning; it is binary STL.

            return true;

        }

        function matchDataViewAt( query, reader, offset ) {

            // Check if each byte in query matches the corresponding byte from the current offset

            for ( var i = 0, il = query.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

                if ( query[ i ] !== reader.getUint8( offset + i, false ) ) return false;

            }

            return true;

        }

        function parseBinary( data ) {

            var reader = new DataView( data );
            var faces = reader.getUint32( 80, true );

            var r, g, b, hasColors = false, colors;
            var defaultR, defaultG, defaultB, alpha;

            // process STL header
            // check for default color in header ("COLOR=rgba" sequence).

            for ( var index = 0; index < 80 - 10; index ++ ) {

                if ( ( reader.getUint32( index, false ) == 0x434F4C4F /*COLO*/ ) &&
                    ( reader.getUint8( index + 4 ) == 0x52 /*'R'*/ ) &&
                    ( reader.getUint8( index + 5 ) == 0x3D /*'='*/ ) ) {

                    hasColors = true;
                    colors = new Float32Array( faces * 3 * 3 );

                    defaultR = reader.getUint8( index + 6 ) / 255;
                    defaultG = reader.getUint8( index + 7 ) / 255;
                    defaultB = reader.getUint8( index + 8 ) / 255;
                    alpha = reader.getUint8( index + 9 ) / 255;

                }

            }

            var dataOffset = 84;
            var faceLength = 12 * 4 + 2;

            var geometry = new BufferGeometry();

            var vertices = new Float32Array( faces * 3 * 3 );
            var normals = new Float32Array( faces * 3 * 3 );

            for ( var face = 0; face < faces; face ++ ) {

                var start = dataOffset + face * faceLength;
                var normalX = reader.getFloat32( start, true );
                var normalY = reader.getFloat32( start + 4, true );
                var normalZ = reader.getFloat32( start + 8, true );

                if ( hasColors ) {

                    var packedColor = reader.getUint16( start + 48, true );

                    if ( ( packedColor & 0x8000 ) === 0 ) {

                        // facet has its own unique color

                        r = ( packedColor & 0x1F ) / 31;
                        g = ( ( packedColor >> 5 ) & 0x1F ) / 31;
                        b = ( ( packedColor >> 10 ) & 0x1F ) / 31;

                    } else {

                        r = defaultR;
                        g = defaultG;
                        b = defaultB;

                    }

                }

                for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i ++ ) {

                    var vertexstart = start + i * 12;
                    var componentIdx = ( face * 3 * 3 ) + ( ( i - 1 ) * 3 );

                    vertices[ componentIdx ] = reader.getFloat32( vertexstart, true );
                    vertices[ componentIdx + 1 ] = reader.getFloat32( vertexstart + 4, true );
                    vertices[ componentIdx + 2 ] = reader.getFloat32( vertexstart + 8, true );

                    normals[ componentIdx ] = normalX;
                    normals[ componentIdx + 1 ] = normalY;
                    normals[ componentIdx + 2 ] = normalZ;

                    if ( hasColors ) {

                        colors[ componentIdx ] = r;
                        colors[ componentIdx + 1 ] = g;
                        colors[ componentIdx + 2 ] = b;

                    }

                }

            }

            geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
            geometry.addAttribute( 'normal', new BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );

            if ( hasColors ) {

                geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
                geometry.hasColors = true;
                geometry.alpha = alpha;

            }

            return geometry;

        }

        function parseASCII( data ) {

            var geometry = new BufferGeometry();
            var patternSolid = /solid([\s\S]*?)endsolid/g;
            var patternFace = /facet([\s\S]*?)endfacet/g;
            var faceCounter = 0;

            var patternFloat = /[\s]+([+-]?(?:\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)/.source;
            var patternVertex = new RegExp( 'vertex' + patternFloat + patternFloat + patternFloat, 'g' );
            var patternNormal = new RegExp( 'normal' + patternFloat + patternFloat + patternFloat, 'g' );

            var vertices = [];
            var normals = [];

            var normal = new Vector3();

            var result;

            var groupVertexes = [];
            var groupCount = 0;
            var startVertex = 0;
            var endVertex = 0;

            while ( ( result = patternSolid.exec( data ) ) !== null ) {

                startVertex = endVertex;

                var solid = result[ 0 ];

                while ( ( result = patternFace.exec( solid ) ) !== null ) {

                    var vertexCountPerFace = 0;
                    var normalCountPerFace = 0;

                    var text = result[ 0 ];

                    while ( ( result = patternNormal.exec( text ) ) !== null ) {

                        normal.x = parseFloat( result[ 1 ] );
                        normal.y = parseFloat( result[ 2 ] );
                        normal.z = parseFloat( result[ 3 ] );
                        normalCountPerFace ++;

                    }

                    while ( ( result = patternVertex.exec( text ) ) !== null ) {

                        vertices.push( parseFloat( result[ 1 ] ), parseFloat( result[ 2 ] ), parseFloat( result[ 3 ] ) );
                        normals.push( normal.x, normal.y, normal.z );
                        vertexCountPerFace ++;
                        endVertex ++;

                    }

                    // every face have to own ONE valid normal

                    if ( normalCountPerFace !== 1 ) {

                        console.error( 'THREE.STLLoader: Something isn\'t right with the normal of face number ' + faceCounter );

                    }

                    // each face have to own THREE valid vertices

                    if ( vertexCountPerFace !== 3 ) {

                        console.error( 'THREE.STLLoader: Something isn\'t right with the vertices of face number ' + faceCounter );

                    }

                    faceCounter ++;

                }

                groupVertexes.push( { startVertex: startVertex, endVertex: endVertex } );
                groupCount ++;

            }

            geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
            geometry.addAttribute( 'normal', new Float32BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );

            if ( groupCount > 0 ) {

                for ( var i = 0; i < groupVertexes.length; i ++ ) {

                    geometry.addGroup( groupVertexes[ i ].startVertex, groupVertexes[ i ].endVertex, i );

                }

            }

            return geometry;

        }

        function ensureString( buffer ) {

            if ( typeof buffer !== 'string' ) {

                return LoaderUtils.decodeText( new Uint8Array( buffer ) );

            }

            return buffer;

        }

        function ensureBinary( buffer ) {

            if ( typeof buffer === 'string' ) {

                var array_buffer = new Uint8Array( buffer.length );
                for ( var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i ++ ) {

                    array_buffer[ i ] = buffer.charCodeAt( i ) & 0xff; // implicitly assumes little-endian

                }

                return array_buffer.buffer || array_buffer;

            } else {

                return buffer;

            }

        }

        // start

        var binData = ensureBinary( data );

        return isBinary( binData ) ? parseBinary( binData ) : parseASCII( ensureString( data ) );

    }

};

export { STLLoader };
```

**Some extra info:**

The file data, when received by my frontend, looks like this: `�u#;�O_?����W�Bt��B���A��B凪B�F�A���BJJ�BȧA�ۢ>#(q>�k?��B`

I've been attempting to encode it as an `ArrayBuffer` using:

```
  var enc = new TextEncoder();
  var arrayBuffer = enc.encode(fileString).buffer;
```

Comment: `STLLoader` has [`.parse()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/0bb21aa8e11ca8ee8410d9eff42dad439ed35c22/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js#L113) method. Try to call this method, passing your data, instead of calling `.load()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is useful to anyone, I finally solved my problem.

First, I had to [fork STLLoader's parse method](https://gist.github.com/BretCameron/ff96fee30da795b0b7224e2a13d411d9).

Second, I had run into problems sending and receiving the file, which I solved by explicitly the content type.

On the server, I made sure to explicitly set the content type to `'binary'`:

```
app.get("/cube", (req, res) => {
  const b = fs.readFileSync("./samples/cube.stl", null);
  res.end(b, 'binary');
});
```

Then, on the client, I set the response type to `'arraybuffer'`:

```
import axios from "axios";
import parseSTL from "./lib/parseSTL";

// ...

axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "/cube",
  responseType: "arraybuffer"
}).then(res => {
  let geometry = parseSTL(res.data);
});
```

After that, everything worked as expected!

Answer (score 5):

Read the dropped file(s) on the client..
Then change the THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.resolveURL method to convert the requested filenames to return the encoded file contents as Blobs.
Then if you need server upload, at that point, you can kick that off and let it run in the background.

Comment: Thanks @manthrax, I've added the `LoadingManager` code (with the `resolveURL` method) to my question. Any chance you could point out specifically where I need to make the change? So far, my attempts have been unsuccessful!

Comment: THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.resolveURL = function( url ){

return myCacheOfUserDraggedFileContents[ url ]
}